# Angular: How to detect (equal) template errors

Tags: angular

Using a custom error handler, is there any chance to tell runtime template errors and *usual* errors apart? If you e.g. put something like `{{x.y}}` in the template, with `x: any;` you'll get an error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'y')

Now this error sure comes again and again with every app cycle. Is there any chance to detect these in an ErrorHandler?

```
export class ErrorService implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error: any): void {
    /*
      Sure this equality doesn't work. But how to tell:
       a) If the error is caused by an Angular Template
       b) If it is the same template error that caused the last call
    */

    if (error == "templateError") {
      if (error ==  lastTemplateError) { return; }
      lastTemplateError = error;
    }
    
    //Handle my error here; using tick to get a recursion, if double error isn't catched
    this.injector.get(ApplicationRef).tick();
  }
  injector = inject(Injector);
  lastTemplateError: any;
}
```

EDIT: To me it seems like this currently isn't possible. I've opened a [Git feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53932). Feel free to promote.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I haven't seen any way to do it (let alone reliably). +1 and hope someone else has something to share.

Comment: Do you want to detect 'undefined' errors in your code, considering that HTML itself does not throw errors?

Comment: I want to detect any runtime template errors caused by Angular (e.g. nullpointer). This is necessary, because every app cycle will (most likely) rise the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it can be done by checking for presense within `stack` of some keyword from template execution(e.g. `at executeTemplate` in dev mode).

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
...
const templateErrorStackPart = isDevMode() ? 'executeTemplate' : 'template';

export class ErrorService extends ErrorHandler {
  override handleError(error: any): void {
    const isTemplateError = error.stack?.includes(`at ${templateErrorStackPart}`);

    if (lastTemplateError && isTemplateError && error.stack == lastTemplateError.stack) {
      return;
    }

    if (isTemplateError) {
      lastTemplateError = error;
    }

    return super.handleError(error);
  }
}
```

Note: I'm using Angular 17 here

Comment: Looks like an acceptable solution, thank you very much! I'll just wait for a more type-safe or similar. Do you maybe know the file (Angular github) where the template errors are created? Maybe they are of a specific type or use some other constants they can get identified by?

Comment: They just catch them by `try catch`https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a2087a1978dfd96a1d426b6814510f642f717fb9/packages/core/src/application/application_ref.ts#L556-L558

Comment: And do you maybe know where the original error is thrown?

Comment: You can find from call stack. It comes from component template factory

Comment: This sure doesn't work compiled / minified ... :/ Any different idea? Guess there just is no chance, right?